# click on a site to add a new image in Squarespace? with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, onclick, squarespace

I am tying to implement a code I got from a superhi tutorial on a squarespace site.  I want to have a gallery that doesn't appear until you click.  Like this site - [studio-push.com](https://studio-push.com)

I have the script written - just not sure how to implement it in squarespace..... any ideas?

```js
    // JavaScript to reveal image on click. 

const images = [
    "Folio-1.jpg",
    "Folio-2.jpg",
    "Folio-3.jpg"
]

let i = 0 

function placeImage(x, y){
    
    const nextImage = images[i]
    const img = document.createImage("img")
    img.setAttribute("src", nextImage)
    img.style.left = x + "px"
    img.style.top = y + "px"
    
    
    // if you want to rotate...
    //img.style.transform = "rotate (" + (Math.random() * 20 - 10) + "deg)"
    
    img.style.transform = "translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0.5)"
    
    document.body.appendChild(img) 
    
    i = i + 1
    
    if (i >= images.length) {
        i = 0 
    }
    
}

document.addEventListener("click", function(event){
    
    event.preventDefault()
    placeImage(event.pageX,event.pageY )
    
})


///on mobile 

document.addEventListener("touchend", function(event){
    
    event.preventDefault()
    placeImage(event.pageX,event.pageY )
    
})
```

Comment: put it in a script tag on your site?

Comment: ??? done. It's not that simple I'm afraid.

Comment: what errors are you getting? Please detail what behaviour you expect vs what behaviour you are seeing.

Comment: perhaps you did it wrong™ note, css `left` and `top` only work if the `position` is not `static` (i.e. the default) ... perhaps you need `img.style.position = "absolute"`

Comment: by the way - instead of `i = i + 1; if (i >= images.length) { i = 0; }` I do `i = (i + 1) % images.length;` - but the choice is yours :p

Comment: Hi @MattEllen  - I'm not seeing anything. Literally nothing. I've put a code block on page but its not showing the script.  I've also put script in code injection, footer.

Comment: @Bravo - Yes I obviously have done it wrong - I am a complete beginner at javascript and to get it to work on squarespace is another matter all together.  I've positioned images with absolute in the css. Might add it to the script though to make it cleaner.

Comment: oh, right - didn't realise squarespace was so hard to add script to!!! Sorry about that. So, if you add a `console.log('My script is running')` does that get output on your browsers developer tool console?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Bravo ok so if I do that I get this: VM16998:1 My script is running

Comment: so, you can put a script in your page ... if you `document.addEventListener("click", function(event){ console.log(event); })` does it log the event?

Comment: @bravo No when i do that it doesnt run.

Comment: Have you tried embed blocks, or the squarespace developer platform?

Comment: Hi Matt  - no. Not sure how to approach that! If I was to put a code block in would I put the js in there or write some html with the images in?

Comment: I have not used squarespace, I'm afraid, so I don't know, but it's worth you looking into.

Comment: Thank you all for all your help. I will investigate further and let you know if I find a solution!